# numpy trimming trailing zeros in byte strings

Tags: python, string, numpy, spacy

I am trying to serialise [spacy.io](https://spacy.io/) documents into byte strings and save them in a `numpy` array.

`spacy` has a `to_bytes` function which produces a `bytearray`. I call `str` on this `bytearray` and insert that string object into a `numpy` array. This works for most documents except those that end with a trailing zero byte.

To reproduce:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b_arr = bytearray(b'\xca\x00\x00\x00n\xff\xff\xff\x19C\x98\xc9\x06\xb18{\xa5\xe0\xaf6\xe3\x9f\xa7\xad\x86\xd6\x8d\xc0\xe6Mo;{\x96xm\x80\xe5\x8c\x9f<!\xc33\x9dg\xd3\xb3D\xf6\xac\x03P\x8do\x07m$r)\x06XBI\xc87\xcao\x83\x1d\xe4\r]\x86\xda\xeb\xb8\x1f\xd5\xcb\xde\xaa\x85r\x0f\xf1=p\xd6\x01\xdc\x83Z|&\xeb\xce|\xf9o\xa0\xe99x\x87\x87\xac\x1b\x17\x08\x000\x92\x10A\x98\x10\x13\x89( 0\x88 "!*N\xf8\xe6\xf4\r\xb1e\xf0\x9d\xfd\x80\xa2G2\x18\xdesv\xec\x85\xf7\xb1\xb3\xb3\xa68\xa7n\xe8BF\xa6\xe0\xb1\x8d\x8d\x9c\xe5\x99\x9bV\xfcE`\x1cI\x92$I\x92$I\x92$%I\x92\xe4\xff\xff\x7f\xd1\xff\xf0T\xa6\xe8\n\x9a\xd3\xffMe0\xa9\x15\xf1|\x00')
>>> b_arr_text = str(b_arr)
>>> b_arr_np = np.asarray([b_arr_text], dtype=np.str)
>>> b_arr_text == b_arr_np[0]
Out[229]: False
>>> len(b_arr_text)
Out[230]: 206
>>> len(b_arr_np[0])
Out[231]: 205
>>> b_arr_np.dtype
Out[232]: dtype('S206')
```

The `numpy` string trims any trailing zeros, the dtype for the fixed length string is the same length as the input text however.

You can see this even from creating any bytestring with trailing zero bytes in an array:

```
>>> np.asarray(['\xca\x00\x00\x00'], dtype=np.str)

Out: array(['\xca'], dtype='|S4')
```

I presume `numpy` deems trailing zeros to be insignificant? However I can't deserialize these bytestrings back to a `spacy` document object.

Is there any way to get `numpy` not to trim the trailing zeros or do I have to stick to Python lists for this scenario?

Comment: Append a dummy non-zero byte before storing and remove it after retrieving?

Comment: @nekomatic thanks for the suggestion, I could do definitely do that and it would work. Ideally I would like to know why `numpy` does this, especially curious about the mismatch between the `dtype` string length and size of the trimmed string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's normal behavior. After `b_arr_np.tostring()` you can see, that all trailing zeros are in order.

```
b_arr = bytearray(b'\xca\x00\x00\x00')

b_arr_text = str(b_arr)

b_arr_np = np.asarray([b_arr_text], dtype=np.str)

b_arr_np
Out[303]: 
array(['\xca'], 
      dtype='|S4')

b_arr_np.tostring()
Out[304]: '\xca\x00\x00\x00'
```

Check post [information loss with bytes type](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3878) from github. Issues are either use trailng non-zero bytes or use `dtype=uint8` with `b_arr`:

```
b_arr_np = np.asarray([b_arr], dtype=np.uint8)

b_arr_np
Out[319]: array([[202,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)

b_arr_np.tostring()

Out[320]: '\xca\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Thanks for this @vadim-shkaberda ..that post explains everything I was wondering about. Sadly your suggestion to use `np.uint8` does not work for me as I have mixed shape bytearrays:

    `np.asarray([bytearray(b'\xca\x00\x00\x00'), bytearray(b'\xca\x00\x00')], dtype=np.uint8)`

Produces a value error:

    `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

As the post suggests I can use the object `dtype` but that loses any benefit of using `numpy` over Python lists. I think I will stick to using the workaround suggested by @nekomatic and append a dummy byte and remove after.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `np.void` dtype.

String or bytes arrays will always chop off the trailing zeros.

```
a = np.array([b"\x00\x00"], dtype=np.str)
a
# Out: array([''], dtype='<U2')
a[0]
# Out: ''
```

But a void array won't.

```
a = np.array([b"\x00\x00"], dtype=np.void)
a
# Out: array([b'\x00\x00'], dtype='|V2')
a[0]
# Out: void(b'\x00\x00')
```

There is a slight complication that each array element is now wrapped in a `void(...)` but you can fix that with either:

```
a[0].item()
# Out: b'\x00\x00'
```

or for the whole array:

```
a = a.astype(object)
a
# Out: array([b'\x00\x00'], dtype=object)
a[0]
# Out: b'\x00\x00'
```

---

If you replace the line

```
b_arr_np = np.asarray([b_arr_text], dtype=np.str)
```

with

```
b_arr_np = np.asarray([b_arr_text], dtype=np.void).astype(object)
```

then your example behaves as you expected it.

Comment: The problem with np.void is that it does not allow variable length elements.